# CSS horizontal menu breaking when zooming Chrome / Safari

Tags: iphone, css, google-chrome, menu, safari

I read many similar topics and I tried the suggestions but it seems I can't get this to work.
I am a self-learner, not a professional just building a website for my parents company and I am having a problem with my menu.
This is working fine in IE and Firefox (at least the versions I have) but Chrome and Safari don't like it. Initially in Chrome it looks good but if you zoom out it's breaking and in Safari for iPhone and iPad it's even worse as the last item on my list is never inline with the rest.
What I read is that I need to to have white-space:nowrap; in my code and I do but it's not helping, I was playing with the position attribute as well but none of the values work. Maybe one strange thing about my menu is that each li has an id tag but that's because I want a different image to hover over each item and that's the way I could thing of doing it. I would really appreciate some help, Thanks

Link to the website and code below:http://redcoral-catering.com/index_catering_redcoral.php

Safari iPhone:

[image: Safari iPhone]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li id="zero"><a href="/index_catering_redcoral.php"> за нас</a></li>

<li id="one"><a  href="/redcoral_services.php"> услуги</a></li>

<li id="two"><a  href="/redcoral_cuisine.php">нашата кухня</a></li>

<li id="three" ><a href="/redcoral_gallery.php">галерия</a></li>

<li id="four"><a  href="/redcoral_movies.php">филми</a></li>

<li id="five"><a  href="/redcoral_celebs.php">кой се е хранил при нас?</a> </li>

<li id="six"><a  href="/redcoral_contacts.php">контакти</a>  </li>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar {
width: 894px;
height: 57px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding-left:25px;
padding-top:1px;
/*clear:both;*/
white-space:nowrap;

}


#navbar ul {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
}
#navbar ul li {
 /* display: block; */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
 /* border-right: 1px solid #1A1A18;*/
}
#navbar ul li ul { display: none; }

#zero{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
}
#one{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
}
#two{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
}
#three{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
}
#four{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
}
#five{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
}
#six{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
}
#seven{
background-image: url(images/menu/short.png);
} 


#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 42px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #851212;
    border: none;
  padding: 10px 28px 5px 28px;

}
#zero a:hover { background-image: url(images/menu/22.png); }
#one a:hover { background-image: url(images/menu/22.png);}
#two a:hover { background-image: url(images/menu/24.png);}
#three a:hover { background-image: url(images/menu/22.png);}
#four a:hover { background-image: url(images/menu/22.png);}
#five a:hover { background-image: url(images/menu/23.png);}
#six a:hover { background-image: url(images/menu/26.png);}


 #navbar ul li a:hover { 
    color: #DF0101;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the following settings:

```
html, body { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}
#navbar {
    width: 857px; /* updated width to center properly */
    height: 57px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    /*padding-left:25px;*/
    padding-top:1px; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
}

#navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #851212;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 26px 5px 26px; /* decreased padding very slightly */
}
```

Also try placing this meta tag in your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Let me know if that solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I tried applying the above but it's still the same unfortunately. I tried the meta tag as well but sadly what happens is that the page is zoomed in and you can't actually zoom out when opened on the iphone, and the last item is still not inline. I was trying before that meta tag as well but again didn't get it to work so I left it. There is a setting that I am missing but still not sure what.  Many thanks for your help

Comment: update: I changed the content width to the actual width of the page, not the device and now I can zoom out on iphone but the menu is still a problem...

Comment: yep, the only way I could think of making it work it to add a specific css file for iphone where there is less padding to make it fit, I'll do the same for ipad as it seems to be broken there as well. 
I have this now in me header: <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/style_iphone.css" type="text/css" />

However still problematic in Google Chrome..... Thanks guys